# How to call a set of .js file in device detection jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am try to call a set of jquery files lower than 800 px and a different set of files for desktop version, but i am getting blank page

here is the code

which i am using

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var wi = $(window).width();

        if (wi >= 801){

document.writeln('<script src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></sc'+'ript>');
document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></sc'+'ript>');
document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/examples.js"></sc'+'ript>');
            }
        else {

            }

});
```

**or**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var wi = $(window).width();

        if (wi <= 800){


            }
        else {
document.writeln('<script src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></sc'+'ript>');
document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></sc'+'ript>');
document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/examples.js"></sc'+'ript>');

            }

});
```

Comment: Why do you add `</sc'+'ript>'`? Just end the tag as you normally would. And add a `<br/>` after your `writeln` call

Comment: @brroshan i tried even as you said but not getting the result

Answer (score 1):

Change your `$(window).load(function()` to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var wi = $(window).width();

    if (wi >= 801){

document.writeln('<script src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>');
document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/examples.js"></script>');
        }
    else {

        }

});
```

Comment: document.writeln('');
document.writeln('');
document.writeln('');}else{}}); i am getting this error or output in my screen

Comment: Try `document.write()`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `$.getScript();` function from jQuery. It load every scrpit you want to your page.

```
$(window).load(function(){
     var wi = $(window).width();

     if (wi >= 801){
        $.getScript("js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js")
        $.getScript("js/jquery.fullPage.js")
        $.getScript("js/examples.js")                    
     }
     else {}

});
```